# How to fix command-line VLC `AudioObjectAddPropertyListener` errors

Tags: macos, audio, vlc-media-player

```
$ vlc -Z --play-and-exit my_music.mp4
VLC media player 3.0.20 Vetinari (revision 3.0.20-0-g6f0d0ab126)
[00007fec32124770] macosx interface error: Updater aborted with error 1001
[00007fec21807100] auhal audio output error: AudioObjectAddPropertyListener failed, device id 269, prop: [atfp], OSStatus: 1852797029
[00007fec21807100] auhal audio output error: AudioObjectAddPropertyListener failed, device id 257, prop: [atfp], OSStatus: 1852797029
[00007fec21807100] auhal audio output error: AudioObjectAddPropertyListener failed, device id 79, prop: [atfp], OSStatus: 1852797029
[00007fec21807100] auhal audio output error: AudioObjectAddPropertyListener failed, device id 91, prop: [atfp], OSStatus: 1852797029
[00007fec21807100] auhal audio output error: AudioObjectAddPropertyListener failed, device id 269, prop: [atfp], OSStatus: 1852797029
[00007fec21807100] auhal audio output error: AudioObjectAddPropertyListener failed, device id 303, prop: [atfp], OSStatus: 1852797029
zsh $ [00007fec32405e50] main playlist: end of playlist, exiting
file: /Users/qazwsx/my_music.mp4
```

```
$ vlc --version
VLC media player 3.0.20 Vetinari (revision 3.0.20-0-g6f0d0ab126)
VLC version 3.0.20 Vetinari (3.0.20-0-g6f0d0ab126)
Compiled by d-fu on Davids-MBP.fritz.box (Nov  1 2023 13:50:16)
Compiler: clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mmacosx-version-min=10.7' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
This program comes with NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
You may redistribute it under the terms of the GNU General Public License;
see the file named COPYING for details.
Written by the VideoLAN team; see the AUTHORS file.
```

On macOS 13.1.

Comment: does the audio/video play correctly? complex software like VLC emmits errors all the time, but many of them can be safety ignored.

Comment: @FrankThomas: Yes. But if the errors could be understood and fixed I'd still be inerested.